# Passing values to another form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can i pass the value of the txtFirstName.Text to the other form? and also the other inputs.(I pasted the two Forms I'm working on). Please Help me. Or is it better to use a MultiDimensional array? Im doing a something-like account login-signup program where you can view the information you input in a Profile with max of 5 accounts. Please help. Thankyou.

```
public partial class frmInfo : Form
{
    public frmInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFirstName.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtFirstName, "Your First Name is important.");
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();
        }

        if (txtLastName.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider2.SetError(txtLastName, "Your Last Name is important.");
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider2.Clear();
        }

        if (txtFirstName.Text != String.Empty && txtLastName.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            frmProfile profile = new frmProfile();
            profile.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}


//Other form
public partial class frmProfile : Form
{
    public frmProfile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void changePasswordToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmChangePassword changepass = new frmChangePassword();
        changepass.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void logOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmMain logout = new frmMain();
        logout.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont expect us to do your home work

Comment: Im not ASKING you to do my homework. I just dont know how to solve it and I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with an Object Oriented Language, so why don't you try to use classes and pass instances of this class.

First define your class with the relevant properties

```
public class Profile
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    .... other properties will follow as you like...
}
```

Now in the click event of your button on the first form

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Profile pf = new Profile();
    if (txtFirstName.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtFirstName, "Your First Name is important.");
        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        pf.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
    .......

    // Pass your Profile class instance to the constructor of the frmProfile
    frmProfile profile = new frmProfile(pf);
    profile.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

And now in the frmProfile class use the instance passed

```
public partial class frmProfile : Form
{
    public frmProfile(Profile pf)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtFirstName.Text = pf.FirstName;
        .....
    }
    .....
}
```

In this way you could pass just one variable that contains all of your data without the need to pass every individual textbox to the frmProfile form

Comment: To avoid a FirstName that contains only spaces. Not empty but surely not a valid name.

Comment: How can I use this in an array? Will I do the same declaration in class?

Comment: Not clear, but I suggest to post a new question with your requirements clearly exposed. In that way more people will look at your question. Feel free to notify me with a comment here with a link to your new question

Comment: Well I just got banned from asking questions. Wth.

Comment: Uhm I see, to much downvotes on your questions. I suggest to remove from your question the unnecessary code. (For example all those empty event handlers) Also revise your other questions to check if they could be made more clear.... See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
frmProfile profile = new frmProfile();
profile.txtFullName.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}",  
                                         txtFirstName.Text, 
                                         txtLastName.Text);
profile.Show();
```

Comment: The name "txtFirstName" does not exist in the current context

Comment: The name "txtLastName" does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You could add two parameters to the constructor of frmProfile. Then, when constructing a new instance of the form, pass the values of your textboxes to the form.

Constructor of frmProfile:

```
public frmProfile(string Firstname, string Lastname) {
    // Do something with Firstname and Lastname
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then when in the btnConfirm_Click function:

```
    if (txtFirstName.Text != String.Empty && txtLastName.Text != String.Empty) {
        frmProfile profile = new frmProfile(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
        profile.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```